# Trouble subscribing PFInstallation to unique channel

Tags: parse-platform

Hey all Im having some trouble trying to subscribe users (the PFInstallation associated with the user) to channels using parse. I am trying to subscribe each user to their own unique channel so that custom notifications can be sent to them.

I have the following code

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    PFUser *u = [PFUser currentUser];
    NSString *i = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user%@", u.objectId ];
    [currentInstallation addUniqueObject:i forKey:@"channels"];
    [currentInstallation setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"user"];
    [currentInstallation save];
```

But whenever it runs I get the following error

```
[Error]: Bad channel name: user_(null) (Code: 112, Version: 1.7.2)
```

Im logging the channel name I'm adding to make sure there aren't any whitespaces or characters that aren't allowed but keep getting the same error.

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: It looks like your `currentUser` doesn't have an `objectId` (or the `currentUser` is `null`). Are you sure you have a logged in user?

Comment: I did not change a thing with this snippet but this morning when I tried again it was working. This snippet is called shortly after a user logs/signs in so it could have something to do with changes I made in that. Thanks for you help though @rickerbh